# org-mode broken dynamic clock: Symbol's function definition is void: org-defvaralias

Tags: emacs, org-mode, elpa

For months I've been enjoying use of the org dynamic clock block (<kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-r</kbd>) to help with my hour clocking. Suddenly I find it's not working, though. The only things I've changed is downloading the list-packages org-contrib and org-mode.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-version`

> Org-mode version 7.8.11

Attempt to update/add dynamic block (<kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-r</kbd>)

> Symbol's function definition is void: org-defvaralias

I tried to do manual execution of `defun`s in some of the org .el files, but that just made things worse. Any suggestions on the cleanest way to fix this?

I actually can't even clock-in anymore, with the same error.

I have verified that this is a result of the `org-contrib` install from ELPA, which seems to break it. This is sad, since I was putting good use to other `org-contrib` files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally got around to fixing this. The key resource was http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html, and the solution boils down to two things I was doing wrong when I tried to install through the `list-packages`:

- Remember to start have emacs running without having opened ANY org files or org-config settings. Best way to do this is <kbd>M-x</kbd>`kill-emacs` and start again with `emacs -q`.
- Add to the top of your .emacs file:

```lisp
;; Configure before loading org mode (package-initialize)  
(package-initialize)
```

I've written a little more about it [here](http://www.toryanderson.com/tech/upgrading-emacs-built-org-mode-4-easy-steps).

Comment: Maybe you should execute`(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)` before `M-x list-packages` in order to install `org-plus-contrib` as well(according to [installation](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html)). BTW, can I just ignore your solution and just delete all the `org` in `/usr/share/emacs/` and then update the `org` in the usual `elpa` way?

Comment: BTW, I don't understand why I should using `emacs -q`(not load built-in org-mode) to install `org` using `elpa`, does loading org-mode before installing will affect the compilation of org-mode???

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if that helps, but you could try:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `load-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org-compat` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Even if it works, this is not the solution, simply an ugly workaround.

Try asking your question on the orgmode mailing list, it gets more audience there.